# React Navigation passing params beetween tab

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-navigation

hey i have a code like this

```
    render() {
        const { navigation } = this.props;
        let title = navigation.getParam('title');
        let TabTaskDetail = createMaterialTopTabNavigator({
            'Detail': {
                navigationOptions: {
                    tabBarLabel: 'Detail',
                },
                screen: Detail
            })

        return (
            <SafeAreaView flex={1}>

                <TabTaskDetail />
            </SafeAreaView>
        );
    } }

class Detail extends Component {
    render() {
      return (
     <Text>
         {this.props.data}
     </Text>

      )
    }
```

}

from my code how to get title (navigation.getParam('title')) to my Detail class?

thanks